# IIS 8.5 Windows 2012 R2 64 bit executing partial asp/vbscript statements

Tags: vbscript

Hi I have a asp page which has following statements

```
<html>
<body>
<%
response.write("My ASP Page")
%>

<% 
Application("name")="Test Page"

 response.write("</br>")

 response.write("Your App Name is " & Application("name"))

 response.write("</br>")
%>
</body>
</html>
```

when I try to run this page under IIS 8.5 it is showing below
My ASP Page
Error '8002801c'

/test.asp line 7

I am using a 32-bit enabled .Net 2.0 Classic application pool.
I am struggling to get rid of this error. Any help on this would be highly appreciated.

Comment: What happens if you use global.asa to set your app variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve this by setting my application pool 32-bit flag to false.